# The mystery of hidden-features tag

Tags: discussion, support, tags, search

Questions asking for hidden features of languages are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and that's fine as I am not here to question that. What I am interested in is the [hidden-features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features) tag itself.

While (all) questions still tagged with it are locked you can easily find them [through google](https://www.google.co.uk/?q=stackoverflow+hidden+features), but when using the internal Stack Overflow search box with `[hidden-features]` as the search query, it returns 0 questions.

[image]

The [excerpt history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5727671/revisions) for the tag is also quite confusing...

**Can anyone explain why the search box shows 0 as a result? How should I interpret this? Is it a bug or is this done on purpose?**

Additionally, since the internal search box does not allow us to see questions tagged with [hidden-features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features) but I think we are still able to tag our questions with [hidden-features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features) tag **do you think** [hidden-features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features) **tag should be removed from the site?**

Comment: At a glance, all of the googleable questions look like they're locked. (Y'know, just in case that detail ends up being important)

Comment: Frankly the problem is the locked questions not appearing in a tag search.  If the questions themselves are so "valuable" that you don't want to delete them, why hide them from users using your internal search.

Comment: To remove the tag we'd need to be able to edit the questions - which we can't do because they're locked....

Comment: Found a way to list them all. Just use some restricting operator in a non-restricting way for the search, like `answers:0..`. Wrote it up here: [How can I find hidden questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260252/how-can-i-find-hidden-questions)

Comment: Those features sure are hidden well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Dennis Meng](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260149/the-mystery-of-hidden-features-tag#comment40583_260149) is spot on, the questions you find with Google have historical locks on them.

From [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

> Historically-locked questions are omitted from normal question lists (those on the home page, /questions, and the various per-tag lists), but can still be found by searching for words in the post or title (via either site-search or Google, etc).

Indeed, if you [search for *Hidden Features of C#*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Hidden+Features+of+C%23) you will find [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c), which is tagged with [hidden-features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features) but also has a historical lock.

Comment: So you could say that it's a hidden feature of the 'Hidden Features' tag, that if you search for its posts directly, they're hidden.

Answer (score 6):

You point out something I'd forgotten about: we never blacklisted this tag. I've remedied that:

[image: The 'hidden-features' tag is not allowed.]

Given these questions cannot be edited, this serves to preserve [the categorization of those in the archives](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhidden-features%5D+is%3Aquestion) while discouraging folks from posting new ones.