# How can I find hidden questions?

Tags: support, locked-posts, burninate-system, historical-lock

For good reasons, questions which are too valuable to delete but just do no longer fit the site get a historical lock.

Aside from making voting/changing impossible (for all but moderators?), those locks remove questions from normal listings, like *newest*, *frequent*, *recent*, *votes* or questions tagged.

While that is right and proper for normal site-operation, it hinders burnination of tags deemed bad.

So, the question is, how can I get a listing of all questions in a tag **including hidden ones**, despite that behavior?

---

Question was inspired by: [The mystery of hidden-features tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260149/the-mystery-of-hidden-features-tag)

A sample hidden question would be: [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python)

Comment: Can you link to an example of a question that's not showing up in a normal tag search?

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Added an example. BTW: Can any moderator remove history-locks / change history-locked pages, or does that need someone higher on the totem-pole?

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to see this in action. I guess this mean that *anyone* can add the `[hidden-features]` tag to a question, even though it appears to have 0 uses [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features)?

Comment: Yes, diamond moderators can add/remove historical locks.

Comment: Yes, and the tag won't be dropped, as it stays in use until a mod (like you) decides to drop it from those locked questions.

Comment: I've thought about it, and I think that tag should stay (for now). It is still useful to find those questions, and with it being hidden, the odds are low that anyone will use it. I'd only consider removing it if there was a problem with people continuing to add it to new questions a lot.

Comment: Google seems helpful, if you want questions in this specific tag: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+hidden-features. Since you're focusing on burninate requests, maybe it would help there, too? Obviously, it would only be helpful once the tag had been removed from all the unhidden questions; then Google might be more inclined to show the hidden results.

Comment: So is not showing up in the search results a property of the tag or of the lock?  if it's the fotmer, does this mean that someone could go on a malicious retagging spree, adding [tag:hidden-features] to lots of questions making them harder to find?  Sounds like a nasty thing to do before rage-quitting (but not too hard to rollback).

Comment: @jpmc: That tag was only my inspiration to look into it. For other tags, especially if the tag is a bit more common as normal text, using google that way won't be nearly as effective. It's a property of this lock, maybe also others, not the tag itself.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It looks like it's the fact that it's locked.

Comment: I came here expecting ninjas, I'm not disappointed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer seems simple:

Use the search-box and enter the tag there.  Trouble is, that does not work: If you only enter tags, you get redirected to the "questons tagged (your tags here)"-page.

Next try was to use some words from the title. That works, if you know the question. 
But you wanted to get them all, not only those you already know well.

Third time does the charm then: follow the relevant tags with a null-value restricting operator.

One such operator: "`answers:0..`" (Questions with at least no answers, haven't found any with less yet ;-))

Or, if you don't want the full list but only locked posts: `locked:1`

Comment: What if your questions were hidden from you?