# Shouldn't I ask a hidden features question?

Tags: discussion

It seems [hidden-features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features) questions are all locked and aren't searchable.

If I ask a similar question, I think the same thing will happen to it. However, I learned a lot from Postgres and Python versions of the series and I guess other people benefited, too. Thus, I'd like to see a similar list/collection for newer languages such as Go and Rust.

By its nature the question's broad and discouraged in Stack Overflow, but it is the best fit in SE, I think.

What do you recommend? Is it totally forbidden or is there a middle ground for this type of question?

Comment: *"Use only for SPECIFIC questions, list-type questions of hidden features are no longer allowed."*

Comment: Maybe we can make “hidden features” lists again with the upcoming Documentation feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the [tag information](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hidden-features/info):

> About <kbd>hidden-features</kbd>: Only used on old and popular locked questions asking for lists of hidden features. Hidden Features is a tag for questions that involve hidden features in a programming language/environment/tool.
>
> This tag is blacklisted (see [The mystery of hidden-features tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260149/the-mystery-of-hidden-features-tag)).

So, in terms of questions *about* hidden features, it's apparent that things like "What are the hidden features of BCPL?" are frowned upon since it's really just looking for a list of things. But, if you wanted to know if a feature is documented somewhere or whether it's just arcane knowledge, you could possibly get away with something like:

> I know BCPL can do `base%index` to do the same thing as C's `base[index]` but what are the `%%`, `%!` and `!%` operators? I've seen them in code but Martin Richards' book doesn't seem to cover them. Are these a hidden feature of the BCPL language?

However, I wouldn't suggest using the tag itself, that's probably going to cause you grief.

Comment: I'd stay away from the "hidden feature" wording entirely -- your suggested question seems just fine asking what the operators do.

Comment: Well, if you want to ask if something is a hidden feature, you're probably going to have to use the words `hidden` and `feature` *somewhere* :-) But, granted, it's possibly not *necessary* to ask that in this case, it was just the best example I could come up with in a hurry. Updated the answer to hopefully improve my intent.