# Was the [hidden-features] tag "unblacklisted"?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki, tag-blocklist

I read in the [tag-info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hidden-features/info) for [hidden-features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features) and in Shog9's answer to [The mystery of hidden-features tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260149#260378) and in paxdiablo's answer to [Shouldn't I ask a hidden features question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310587#310591) that this tag is blacklisted.

Yet I was able to [post this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54910998/this-is-just-a-test) with the [hidden-features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features) tag. (10k+ link, I deleted the question almost immediately.) And it seems that there were other questions with this tag posted *after* the answers I linked above. [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/883845/deleted-questions-with-a-given-tag?Tagname=hidden-features) returns three (deleted) questions from 2018 which have this tag and `CreationDate` in 2018.

So I suppose that:

- Either the wording of the tag-info should be corrected, since the tag isn't actually blacklisted.
- Or the tag should be blacklisted again, if this is just an oversight.

And, of course, there is also a third option that:

- I misunderstood something when reading other posts about this tag.

---

I will add that I did not do this to cause trouble. There was a discussion on another per-site meta about blacklisting a tag in order to prevent it from being added to a new question. I wanted to test for myself how this warning on a live tag, which is blacklisted, looks. So I have put `hidden-features` in the tags field. Since I saw nothing, I thought: "Maybe I will be shown the warning when I attempt to post the question." but - to my surprise - I was allowed to post the question.

[image: Screenshot for hidden-features]

I would have more luck if I did the same experiment with [code-golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). After typing the tag and leaving the tags field I was shown a warning saying that: "The 'code-golf' tag is not allowed." (Followed by the tag advice displayed in red.)

[image: Screenshot for code-golf]

Comment: Blacklist items automatically expire if they are never triggered for some amount of time. It's possible no one tried to use it for too long.

Comment: @animuson Is it known after which period tag-blacklists expire? Is this true also for all blacklisted input, or just for tags?

Comment: Ask Raymond Reddington.

Comment: Have you considered this to actually be a [hidden-feature]?

Comment: Looked this up. Blacklist items automatically expire if they aren't matched over a period of 90 days, and are at least 60 days old. Tags are excluded from this check, **but** the exclusion was not added until March of 2015. So we'd need to add it back in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for noticing! As animuson noted, we used to age away these tag blacklists. Which is annoying, because I had to re-type that whole message. That done, it's now **back in black**...list:

[image: Blocked with message: "Hidden features of..." questions were allowed during the early days of Stack Overflow, but quickly became swamped with features that were not hidden or even particularly obscure. While some questions in this tag are maintained for historical reasons, new questions of this form are no longer accepted.]

Comment: Why blacklist it again? If it had aged away, doesn't it mean that it wasn't being triggered at all?

Comment: It means nobody tried to submit a question or edit with the tag for 90 days. Which for most blacklists is a pretty solid indication that the blacklist isn't needed anymore... For tags that should never be used, ever again, it usually just means that every 4 months someone has something else to gripe about while either removing the tag or deleting the question using it or both. 13 questions in 3 years is almost nothing, but still... shouldn't have been even that many.

Comment: FYI, it's only black because Shog lives and breathes noir. It's red.

Comment: I am curious why there is an age-away feature on blacklisted tags. It would make sense - well in my view - that something on a blacklist does not get "aged away" after all.

Comment: There isn't anymore @KarelG. There used to be, because there was an aging feature on everything else in the blacklist - if we're blocking, say, a particular phrase common to a given spam campaign, that doesn't need to stay blocked once the campaign ends. But the use-case for tag blacklists is rather different.